# ability to change the ModelMetadataProviders.Current in areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, modelmetadata

I have a special case where I would need the ability to use multiple ModelMetadaProviders in an application. Certain area would use a specific provider, another area will use some other. I mainly need this because each of those providers uses different resource file for providing resource strings.

I have it working for one and I wire it up in the global.asax.cs:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider<i18n>();
```

Now in the Admin area I want to do this:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider<AdminRes>();
```

The above doesn't work but does not throw an error also. It just doesn't do the resource string lookups.

Is this achievable and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one can be used for the entire site. Isn't it possible to add more resource assemblies to  the current `LocalizedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`?